# Where does this shloka appear in Mahabharata? "Janami dharmam na cha me pravrttih..."

Tags: mahabharata, identification-request, shloka

Where does this shloka appear in Mahabharata? It was said by Duryodhana to Krishna. Can someone tell me which chapter etc?

> Janami dharmam na cha me pravrttih,
>   janamyadharmam na cha me nivrttih;
>   kenapi devena hrdi sthitena yatha niyuktosmi tatha karomi"
>
> Meaning - "I know what is dharma, yet I cannot get myself to follow it! I know what is adharma, yet I cannot retire from it! O Lord of the senses! You dwelt in my heart and I will do as you impel me to do."

Comment: How are you sure it is from Mahabharata? The story of Pandava , Kauravas et cetera is mentioned in many Scriptures, not just Mahabharata

Comment: I am not sure, which is why I am asking!

Comment: so you should ask "Is this shloka present in Mahabharata.....?". This shloka is found in Pandava Geeta and Vidyaranya Madhava as Pandya has answered. Maybe this shloka is not even present in Mahabharata. So kindly edit it.

Comment: Thanks Anurag for correcting my grammar & semantics (which I didn't ask for)! Surprisingly, others are able to understand my question and have also answered. I am grateful for their understanding. Now if you are done criticizing me on how to ask a question, may I suggest that you go mind something else? Thank you for your time!

Comment: no I do not mean to criticise you. Yu got me wrong. I completely understood your question, it was just a suggestion to make it more clear. For example like asking "**Is this Shloka found in MB...**" gives the clear way meaning that you are asking whether or not it is in MB, and "**Where this Shloka is in MB...**" at first looks like you know that this Shloka is in MB and you are asking which chapter is it from. It was only a suggestion so that the question becomes clear.

Comment: We here always suggest each other for better formatting, making questions and answers clear, any unnoticed errors. It is not done to criticise anyone. Apologies if you felt that but I had no such intentions.

Comment: Mahatvat bharavat vacha Mahabharat mucchate

Comment: Just a comment (not related to the answer though!): A more correct translation to the last line would be: ...(as if) There is some god residing in my heart impel me to do what I do."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure about Mahabharata however can be found in [Pandava Gita](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/pandavagita.html?lang=sa) (also known as Prapanna Gita):

> दुर्योधन उवाच ।
>   जानामि धर्मं न च मे प्रवृत्ति-
>           र्जानामि पापं न च मे निवृत्तिः ।
>   केनापि देवेन हृदि स्थितेन
>           यथा नियुक्तोऽस्मि तथा करोमि ॥ ५७॥
>
> duryodhana uvāca ।
>   jānāmi dharmaṃ na ca me pravṛtti-
>    rjānāmi pāpaṃ na ca me nivṛttiḥ ।
>   kenāpi devena hṛdi sthitena yathā niyukto'smi tathā karomi ॥ 57॥

And also present in [Panchadashi](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_major_works/panchadashi.html?lang=sa) of Vidyaranya Madhava.

> जानामि धर्मं न च मे प्रवृत्ति-
>        र्जानाम्यधर्मं न च मे निवृत्तिः ।
>   केनापि देवेन हृदि स्थितेन
>        यथा नियुक्तोऽस्मि तथा करोमि ॥ १७६॥

Comment: Now the question is where is Pandava Gita in Mahabharata?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help me research further. Appreciate very much!